# Write a query that shows the highest average progress in the system also progress should be rounded to one decimal place

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select c.name , round (avg(sC.progress),1) Average_progress
from course c
join studentCourse sC on sC.courseid=c.id
group by c.name
having max avg(sC.progress)
```

its coming up as an error around "(avg(sC.progress),1)"
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try removing that extra space between round and (?

Comment: The having clause wont give you the correct data.  Can you please explain better how many rows you expect to return.  Are you looking for the course with the highest average for a single user?

Comment: `having max avg(sC.progress)` is not a legal clause. What do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an `order by` and `limit`:

```
select c.name, round(avg(sC.progress),1) Average_progress
from course c join
     studentCourse sC
     on sC.courseid = c.id
group by c.name
order by avg(sC.progress) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: @AsiaArmand . . . As the OP, you should accept this (or another answer) that best answers the question.

Comment: I don't know how to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select *
from (
  select c.name, round (avg(sC.progress), 1) as Average_progress
  from course c
  join studentCourse sC on sC.courseid = c.id
  group by c.name
) x
order by Average_progress desc
limit 1
```

Result:

```
name      Average_progress 
--------- ---------------- 
Course 2             250.5
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jurYGxjL2iVcZtSbbRevp8/0).

Comment: there is no order by though

Comment: I'm looking for the course with the highest average for multiple users

Comment: The running example shows multiple rows being aggregated and the average is computed; then, the course with the highest average is selected and all the other ones are discarded. I think this is what you asked for. If it's not please add a few rows of sample data to your question.